# How to create all day event in Google calendar api from Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

Please forgive me if this is an old question, I couldn't find a solution for this issue.
I want to create all day event on google calendar from my Laravel application, according to the doc startDate and endDate should be same like startDate='2021-12-15' and endDate='2021-12-15'.

if I format the dates like this;

```
$startDateTime = Carbon::parse('2021-12-15')->toRfc3339String();
$endDateTime = Carbon::parse('2021-12-15')->toRfc3339String();
```

event created on Google calendar is like bellow
[image]

how to form the dates to create an event like bellow
[image]

If I format the dates like `$startDateTime = Carbon::create('2021-12-15')->format('Y-m-d');`   and      `$endDateTime = Carbon::create('2021-12-15')->format('Y-m-d');` I get this error;
`Google\Service\Exception { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "badRequest", "message": "Bad Request" } ], "code": 400, "message": "Bad Request" } }`

a link to documentation
https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events

Comment: `->toRfc3339String()` returns `2021-12-13T18:40:54+00:00` (Date, Time and Zone). Can you simply do a `->format('Y-m-d')`, that would generate `2021-10-13`. Or maybe try with modifiers `->startOfDay()` and `->endOfDay()` to set the time to `00:00:00` and `11:59:59` respectively.

Comment: Dear Tim if I format the dates like `$startDateTime = Carbon::create('2021-12-15')->format('Y-m-d');
        $endDateTime = Carbon::create('2021-12-15')->format('Y-m-d');`  I get this error `Google\Service\Exception
{ "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "badRequest", "message": "Bad Request" } ], "code": 400, "message": "Bad Request" } }`.

Comment: Please add that to your question next time, not as a Comment. ``` are not valid in the comments. But, that being said, can you include the documentation for this in your question? If the API is expecting the dates in a specific format, then yeah, `Y-m-d` won't work. Maybe there's a flag for all day?

Comment: if i do write `$startDateTime = Carbon::create('2021-12-15')->startOfDay();` and same for end of day, dates are formatted as `2021-12-15 23:59:59.999999 UTC (+00:00)` and  `2021-12-15 23:59:59.999999 UTC (+00:00)` but created event still is not all day.

Comment: So again, can you post the link to the official documentation for this so I can better help you?

Comment: added a link to documentation can check please

Comment: The documentation notes `start: {date, dateTime, timeZone}` and `end: {date, dateTime, timeZone}`, you haven't shown any code on how you're actually sending this to the API, but I suspect that if you set `date` instead of `dateTime`, and use `->format('Y-m-d')`, it would work.

Comment: Thanks Tim, it solved now. I was using `start.dateTime` instead of `start.date`.

Answer (score 0):

First thanks to [Tim lewis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3965631/tim-lewis) for asking for more details in the comments.
As mentioned in the google documentation you provide:

For `start.date`:

> The date, in the format "yyyy-mm-dd", if this is an all-day event.

and for `start.dateTime`:

> The time, as a combined date-time value (formatted according to RFC3339). A time zone offset is required unless a time zone is explicitly specified in timeZone.

So in nutshell, if you want to set an **all-day event** you should fill `start.date` and `end.data` with `y-m-d` date format and, for a **normal event** you should fill `start.dateTime` and `end.dateTime`. please remember that you can provide a timezone in `start.timeZone` if needed.

P.S. You also can use `start.dateTime` for an all-day event, you just need to add the exact time (e.g. 2021-12-15 00:00:00) and 23:59:59 goes for `end.dateTime`. But using this option might cause some errors when you use a different timezone than the calendar.

Comment: Thanks Mahdi, I was mistaking in; `start.dateTime` instead of `start.date`. It solved now.